# Paging3-PagingDataAdapter，How to remove item?

Tags: android, paging

Android Paging3 alpha03, How to remove or update item?

Help，please

Comment: Hello, please describe your problem more detailed. What exactly did you try? What is your goal? What errors did you encounter? More details help other people to understand your problem better.

Comment: check this article https://sourcediving.com/crud-operations-with-the-new-android-paging-v3-5bf55110aa4d

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate with questions about Paging 2, which is a completely different library?

Comment: pagingAdapter.refresh() working for me

Answer (score 3):

The only way to update the backing dataset currently is to call `PagingSource.invalidate` to trigger another `REFRESH`, which then reloads from current position via `PagingSource.getRefreshKey(state)`.

e.g.,

```
val backingDataSet = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
class MyPagingSource : PagingSource<Int, Int> {
    override suspend fun load(...) = Page(
        data = backingDataset,
        nextKey = null,
        prevKey = null,
        itemsBefore = 0,
        itemsAfter = 0
    )

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Int>) = state.anchorPosition
}

...

var currentPagingSource: MyPagingSource? = null
val pager = Pager(...) {
    MyPagingSource().also{
        currentPagingSource = it
    }
}

...

// To remove an item
backingDataSet.removeAt(0)
currentPagingSource.invalidate()
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I specify to refresh the second page data?

Comment: Currently you must invalidate the entire source.

Comment: @dlam What about using `peek()` to modify an item and then calling `notifyItemChanged`? Is this a bad approach?

Comment: @FlorianWalther Always invalidate after updates to the backing dataset. Trying to sync local state with paginated backing data is really hard to do correctly and you won't get help on that path. For example, how will you resolve races between notifyItem and a prepend or a drop? Another hard case is restoring from cached PagingData, you will need to figure out what is presented and re-insert the correct item. SavedState is even more complicated. So I would definitely not recommend to try to be clever by using notify directly.

Comment: @dlam Thank you for the input. If I have 500 paginated items on the list a call to `invalidate` will reload them all from the source? Is that correct?

Comment: @dlam I don't understand what you're referring to about "cached PagingData" and SavedState. Paging 3 reloads the whole page after process death, right? So it should get the updated data. Screen rotation works as well because I've updated the list that backs the adapter.

Comment: It depends on your initialLoadSize and/or pageSize. Invalidate will reload, but you should implement getRefreshKey to resume from last bound item and ensure you load around the entire viewport (+/- 1 page at minimum) but its very crucial to to have a single source of truth or things will get quickly out of hand. So invalidate will call getRefreshKey to figure out how to resume loading and only load data centered around user's position, not all 500 items.

Comment: Answering your questions - SavedState case without RemoteMediator and placeholders enabled will work automatically. On process death, yes things are reloaded starting from initialKey. There is a .cachedIn operator which condenses the internal event stream in a PagingData and multicasts it within a scope, this cached event will be out-of-date if you update items manually without going through paging and its important you make use of this operator as well